# Why doesn't this rotate3d() CSS transform work as expected in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to create a "card flip" effect using CSS transforms and transitions. I'm using a `<div>` to represent the card, and two child `<div>`s to represent the front and back faces of the card. Both faces are absolutely positioned on top of each other, and the latter has a 180-degree transform to turn it backwards.

I created a jsFiddle to illustrate my current approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/sCyLV/1/

The effect works as intended in Chrome & Firefox (latest versions). However, in IE10, the card appears to flip on both axes, and the back side of the card doesn't appear as the card is flipped - I just see the back side of the front card. Does anyone know why?

I would also love to hear any alternative ideas to accomplish this effect. The only functional requirement is that this effect has to be repeatable in the same direction - i.e., the card will flip in a continuous loop as if it's spinning about the y-axis. Once I get the flipping behavior under control, I will be dynamically swapping out the content on the backside upon each 180-degree rotation, leading to new content being shown on its face each time it turns around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation works as I assume you intended when you use a `rotateY(180deg)` in `transform`.

That gets you the flip effect working normally, but the `z-index` is still out. To get around that I've just swapped the order of the `div`s and animated the `side`s individually rather than as one in the parent because IE10 seems to have an issue with `preserve-3d`.

Here's your fiddle for [IE10](http://jsfiddle.net/sCyLV/2/) (note: I've broken the other browsers, but you just need to replicate the browser-specific properties)

Comment: Awesome - thanks @Klors! I tried to take iterative steps from my approach to your solution, and I wasn't able to get a straight y-axis spin just by changing from rotate3d() to rotateY(); but, the effect started working once I transformed the sides individually. Ultimately I was able to leave the <div> order the same and preserve z-index, and it works in Chrome, Firefox & IE10: http://jsfiddle.net/sCyLV/3/ - thanks again!